# In what order do creatures return from the graveyard with "March from the Tomb"?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

In which order are cards returned from the graveyard with [March from the Tomb](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=401947):

> Return any number of target Ally creature cards with total converted mana cost 8 or less from your graveyard to the battlefield.

In particular, if one of the returned cards is [Kalastria Healer](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=401929):

> Rally — Whenever Kalastria Healer or another Ally enters the battlefield under your control, each opponent loses 1 life and you gain 1 life.

Can I return Kalastria first such that the additional allies entering the battlefield trigger the `Rally` ability?

Comment: There is no order. The card says to return them all at the same time. (And they'll all see each other enter for the purposes of triggered abilities like that; see the proposed duplicate.)